# FSM machine in VHDL with each state DOING CERTAIN OPERATIONS

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I have a FSM with five states (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5).

However, for each state, a sequence of operations should be done. For example, in s2, a counter should count from 1 to 10.

Here comes my question: how could the FSM know that "I should change from s2 to s3"? Or to speak in another way, how could s2 inform FSM that "I am done", and new state should be started according to a LookUpTable?

Answer (score 5):

This is really a non-issue if you code your FSMs in a decent style. Example:

```
architecture RTL of dut is
    type state_t is (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
    signal state     : state_t;
    signal counter   : integer;
    signal condition : boolean;
begin
    fsm : process is
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            case state is
                when s1 =>
                -- do stuff
                when s2 =>
                    if condition then
                        counter <= 0;
                        state   <= s3;
                    end if;
                when s3 =>
                    if counter = 10 then
                        state <= s4;
                    else
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                    end if;
                when s4 =>
                    null;
                when s5 =>
                    null;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process fsm;

end architecture RTL;
```

Comment: Hi Philippe. Thanks for your reply!  Here is what I am trying to use three processes to implement the FSM. In process 1, state_reg <= state_next, In process  2, state_next will be updated. In process 3, output logic will be implemented. My question was actually how to communicate between process 3 and process 2. So that when state operation of process 3 is finished, process 2 knows that state_next should be updated.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @richieqianle: please consider not using three processes and doing it the way Philippe suggests... I find it much easier to handle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409532/vhdl-process-style